# Docker image create very slow under proxy network

Tags: node.js, docker, proxy, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I'm using Docker 1.12.3 and I'm trying to create an image on top of Node + Yarn. When I run `yarn install` it takes around 5 seconds to install when there is a `yarn.lock` file present. I'm inside a corporate network with proxy configured. At home is even faster than 5 seconds.

On the other hand, when I run this command:

```
docker build -t alansouzati/testing . --build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://PROXY:PORT
```

The yarn install hangs in there forever. If I enter an existing image and try `yarn install` inside the container it works perfectly.

So this leads me to believe this is nothing wrong with my proxy configuration but with the Docker build creation process. I have tried to use `network=host` in the build command but it did not help.

Any recommendation on how to improve the Docker image creation when inside a proxied network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation I realised that my base image was the problem, I was using:

`mhart/alpine-node:6.9.1`

Switching to

`kkarczmarczyk/node-yarn`

did the trick.

I guess Alpine node is to small and is removing something that is important for the proxy/network configuration